# SqlParameter for Double, Float or Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this `SqlParameter` like so:

```
SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter("@StageDaysBehind", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter3.Value = schedVarSaveClass.StageDaysBehind;
parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);
```

`schedVarSaveClass.StageDaysBehind` is a double and has a value of 2.5 but it insert into the database as 2, how do I get it to insert as 2.5 and not 2?

I tried this:

```
SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter("@StageDaysBehind", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter3.Value = schedVarSaveClass.StageDaysBehind;
parameter3.Precision = 2;
parameter3.Scale = 5;
parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your parameter is a `SqlDbType.Decimal` but you haven't specified the *precision* and *scale*. I believe scale defaults to `0` in which case you have no digits after the decimal point. Assign the `Precision` and `Scale` properties to the values in the data type as defined in the column, `decimal(p,s)`.

Comment: Can you put that into an answer please with an example, I tried setting Precision and Scale, but same result, saves 2.5 as 2

Comment: Precision as 18, scale as 2

Comment: In your code you should use Precision 18, scale 2

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the problem with minimal setup *without* setting precision and scale.  `DECLARE @Temp TABLE ([Value] [decimal](18, 2)); INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (@StageDaysBehind); SELECT [Value] FROM @Temp;` Setting the `Value` property to either a `Single`, `Double`, or `Decimal` value works. It selects `2.5` as `decimal`.

Comment: Can you pass the parameter the same way but then run `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@StageDaysBehind, 'Precision'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@StageDaysBehind, 'Scale');` ? Without setting `Precision` and `Scale`, I believe it will infer them as 2 and 1. Setting `Precision` to 18 and `Scale` to 2, you should get those values back. Confirming that, it's something in how your SQL script or stored procedure is using the variable.

Comment: Can you show your insert SQL *and* your table definition.

Answer (score -3):

Considering use **AddWithValue** instead, like this:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIELD1",yourValue)
```

It will take care of the type better: decimal, float, etc.

Comment: Actually its highly recommended *NOT* to use AddWithValue e.g. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/